# Filtering a Data.Map against its values, compilation error

Tags: haskell, dictionary, filter

I would like to filter a Data.map against its values; more precisely the map keys are `(Int,Int)` and the value is of type Int.
I want to keep only entries where the key is >=2

here is the function creating the map:

```
countElems :: [(Int,Int)] -> M.Map (Int,Int) Int
countElems = M.fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1)
```

Here is the (wrong) code filtering this map:

```
let elems = countElems $ take 10000 liste7
let elems2 = filter (\i -> i > 2) elems
putStrLn $ show elems2
```

The error is at the filter line:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
            with actual type `M.Map (Int, Int) Int'
In the second argument of `filter', namely `elems'
In the expression: filter (\ i -> i > 2) elems
In an equation for `elems2': elems2 = filter (\ i -> i > 2) elems
```

I don't understand this error message.

Comment: The error says filter expects something of type `[a0]` for some `a0`, whereas you gave it a `Map (Int,Int) Int`. The problem is simple, you are using `Prelude.filter` but you want `Data.Map.filter` (or `M.filter`).

Comment: You are saying that key is of type `(Int,Int)` but you want to keep the entries where the key is `>= 2`. Can you see the problem ?

Comment: thanks, replacing filter by M.filter works; @Sibi : you're wrong : filter filters by the values. thanks anyway